# Is it possible to transfer fuel with a probodobodyne OKTO in the middle?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I want to transfer fuel between two tanks while they are docked in orbit.

The thing is, one of the tanks has a Probodobodyne OKTO between the docking port and the tank.

I don't want to use any transfer fuel mods like Quantum Fuel Transfer.

Is it possible to transfer the fuel with the Probodobodyne in the middle or is it going to be a problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

**For automatic fuel flow:** Having objects in between fuel tanks doesn't matter unless - it's a separator or a docking port with crossfeed turned off and it's on by default.

**For manual fuel transfer:** Having objects in between fuel tanks doesn't ever matter.

Comment: Manual fuel transfer will require a building upgrade. VAB, I think.

Comment: @SergiiZaskaleta Manual fuel transfer requires a [Level 2 Research and Development Facility](http://wiki.kerbalspaceprogram.com/wiki/Research_and_Development#Levels)

Comment: Some items (e.g. Grapping Unit, Aerodynamic Nose Cone) are marked as 'No Fuel Crossfeed'. These will stop automatic flow if in the middle (should not occur during design because most of these only have one attachment node).

Answer (score 2):

It does not matter at all if your tanks and engines are next to each other or separated by a part (that allows *crossfeed*). OKTO allows crossfeed, but some parts don't. For example, fuel *does not automatically get transferred* when you have a decoupler in the middle. In the case of the decoupler, you will see a **No fuel crossfeed!** message orange text when you select the decoupler in the VAB. **No fuel crossfeed** is when you cannot *crossfeed* fuel between tanks on either end.

You can however still transfer fuel by holding <kbd>⎇ alt</kbd> and clicking on the 2 tanks you want to transfer between. You will see a button **In** and a button **Out**. You can click these to transfer fuel (and any other resource)

Answer (score 0):

It also requires that a Kerbal be there.  Haven't tried with an unmanned pod but that was my issue when refueling didn't work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).